Mac and old Adobe Flash: HSTS behaviour
i begin by saying that I am recently 'obsessed' with my past browsing history with my old Mac (2017).
So the question: do you know what happens to a 'settings.sol' file (included in the path Macromedia-support-flash player-sys-url) when the HSTS max Age expires and the url Is not visited After the First visit that created the file?
Example: website URL Is visited on January 1st, the 'settings.sol' file for that URL Is created showing HSTS starting date January 1st and HSTS max Age 180 days (in seconds). What happens to the file After June 30th when the HSTS policy expires?
I have a settings.sol file having, let's Say,those HSTS info (January 1st and 180 days) which appears to be created and modified on June 6th even though the browsing history says that that website was visited only on January 1st and not on June 6th. Is It possible that Flash Player used to automatically update the settings.sol files having an expired HSTS policy?
